# when orientation changes, somehow a buton's onclicklistener called

Tags: android, onclick, orientation

the view that problem occurs has one button and one tabhost inside it.
the button's onclick listener changes some text in current tab.
the problem is when I change the orientation(port to land or land to port), the button's onclicklistener is called/skimmed somehow and text in current tab changes. why is this happening and what is the solution?

```
myActivity extends Activity{
    onCreate(bundle){
        ..
        ..
        add(button1);
        button1.onClickListner(new OnClickListener(){
             ..
             someAlertDialog.show();             //line xxx

        });
    }

}
```

it does not show any alert dialog actually(it is not supposed to do so) but says there is a leakage @line xxx in errorlog.
the whole log is coming soon.

edit: I cannot get error log now, but something weird is still happening after orientation changes.

Comment: What can we assume without code you did so far?

Comment: the code is long about 500 line, and trying to prepare SSCCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens by default on an orientation change is that the current activity instance is destroyed and then recreated and passed the previous instance's state. If a dialog is on screen when this happens it will leak the window that's displaying it.

Since you are not using `Activity#showDialog` which will manage dialogs when `onDestroy` is called you have to do that manually. So you'll have to override `Activity#onDestroy` and call `Dialog#dismiss` if it is showing.